# Why nfsd clears S_ISUID bit in SETATTR if I try to set S_ISUID and owner at the same time?

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs

NFSv3 protocol [specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#section-3.3.2) that SETATTR can set file/dir mode and owner at the same time (as well as few other things). And yet [Linux implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8313064c2e75542201e557e2b496668811c2484a/fs/nfsd/vfs.c#L311) of nfsd behaves in a quite strange way:

```
/* Revoke setuid/setgid on chown */
if (!S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode) &&
    ((iap->ia_valid & ATTR_UID) || (iap->ia_valid & ATTR_GID))) {
    iap->ia_valid |= ATTR_KILL_PRIV;
    if (iap->ia_valid & ATTR_MODE) {
        /* we're setting mode too, just clear the s*id bits */
        iap->ia_mode &= ~S_ISUID;
        if (iap->ia_mode & S_IXGRP)
            iap->ia_mode &= ~S_ISGID;
    } else {
        /* set ATTR_KILL_* bits and let VFS handle it */
        iap->ia_valid |= (ATTR_KILL_SUID | ATTR_KILL_SGID);
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this? I spent a lot of time tracking it down in some old app (that for some reason could not copy a file via NFS without losing suid bit). Is it a bug? It happens even if new owner is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Linux implementation of NFS server. See [NFS specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#page-33).

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SUID is some sort of protection against *untrusted* NFS servers: If administrator of your local machine doesn't trust the NFS server, it cannot afford to execute files from the server with root privileges. See also article [NFS, no_root_squash and SUID - Basic NFS Security](http://fullyautolinux.blogspot.ru/2015/11/nfs-norootsquash-and-suid-basic-nfs.html).

Comment: I understand this. But... 1. there is no check for owner/group to actually change. 2. Nothing prevents attacker from making two calls (one to set owner, another to set suid bit). 3. all other devices (netapp/etc) process calls like this just fine.

Comment: Besides, this code does not disable suid -- it tries to mimic Linux semantic of resetting suid/gid when certain file attributes change. Which is doesn't seem right, when I also try to set suid/gid in the same call.